# tree: root to leaf sum (recursion)

Tags: java, recursion, tree

the problem is: calculate the total sum of all root-to-leaf numbers. for example: if the tree is (1,2,3), 1 is root, 2 is left child, 3 is right child, two paths: 1->2 1->3, sum=12+13=25

this is my correct recursive solution. in the helper method, return the sum:

```
public int sumNumbers(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return getSum(root, 0);
}
private int getSum(TreeNode root, int value) {
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        return root.val + value * 10;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    if (root.left != null) {
        sum += getSum(root.left, value * 10 + root.val);
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        sum += getSum(root.right, value * 10 + root.val);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

but when I add the `sum` as a parameter in the helper method, I always got 0.

```
public int getSum(TreeNode root) {
    int sum = 0, path = 0;
    helper(root, path, sum);
    return sum;
}
private void helper(TreeNode root, int path, int sum) {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    int path = 10 * path + root.val;
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        sum += path;
        return;
    }
    helper(root.left, path, sum);
    helper(root.right, path, sum);
}
```

I believe there must be some points I misunderstand about the recursion. thank you in advance to give me some explanation why the value of `sum` is not 'transferred' back to the `sum` in `getSum` method.

Comment: Java is pass by value. When you are doing `helper(root, path, sum);` in your `getSum` method, it won't update the sum variable you pass as parameter.

Comment: @ZouZou thanks. so, no matter what happened in helper method, the sum in getSum remains the same. but if, maybe the argument is a List<Integer>, the value will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Also you need to think about overflow. My solution has passed in LeetCode, hopefully it gives you some tips.


public class Solution {
    private long sum = 0;
    public int sumNumbers(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return 0;
        sum(root, new Stack<Integer>());

        if(this.sum >= Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return (int)this.sum;
    }

    private void sum(TreeNode node, Stack<Integer> stack){
        if(node == null) return;
        stack.push(node.val);
        if(node.left == null && node.right == null){
            long tempSum = 0;
            int index = 0;
            for(int i=stack.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
                int k = stack.get(i);
                int times = (int)Math.pow(10, index++);
                k *= times;
                tempSum += k;
            }
            this.sum += tempSum;
        }

        sum(node.left, stack);
        sum(node.right, stack);
        if(stack.size() > 0) 
            stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ZouZou is right about the pass by value, although this only applies to primitives. Changing your sum to an Integer instead of int should do the trick, other solution would be to us a global variable (i.e. field)

Comment: Wrong this also applies to references. The trick to understand is that references are passed by value. Furthermore, Integer is immutable.

Comment: agreed, Integer is immutable, autoboxing is doing it's mind tricks again on me. And if you put it that way (references passed as values) you may argue it's all pass by value, although may be surprised, i also heard the term call-by-object-sharing. nevertheless, the second suggestions will work.